# Como passar pela página de alerta de Conexão Insegura do Firefox com GeckoDriver?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, firefox, geckodriver

Como passar pela tela de erro de certificado (conexão insegura) com o WebDriver GeckoDriver para Firefox?

Estou batendo em uma URL que apresenta esse alerta.

Já adicionei nas exceções do browser, mas o problema continua.
Se desmarco a opção "**Consultar servidores OCSP para confirmar a validade atual dos certificados**" continua o problema após o WebDriver iniciar uma sessão do browser.

Carrego o profile do mesmo pelo padrão do sistema:

```cs
private static IWebDriver GetWebDriver(string path)
{
    const string firefoxPath = @"...firefox.exe";

    var service = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService(@"...GeckoDriver\");
    service.FirefoxBinaryPath = firefoxPath;

    var options = new FirefoxOptions
    {
        Profile = GetFirefoxProfile(path),
    };

    var driver = new FirefoxDriver(service, options, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));

    return driver;
}
```

Mas mesmo assim não funciona.

Inclusive tentei setar:

```cs
options.Profile.AcceptUntrustedCertificates = true;
options.Profile.AssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer = true;

profile.SetPreference("acceptInsecureCerts", true);
```

Comment: Poste uma foto da página.... talvez se você clicar em "Avançado" no final da página, e depois em "Continuar mesmo assim", você possa acessar a página.

Comment: @dot.Py olá, é esse tipo de página mesmo que aparece. Mas como fazer isso com o WebDriver? Em exceções do browser já está. Grato!

Comment: Encontrei essa solução para python dê uma fuçada no código pra ver se encontra algo parecido:


profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.accept_untrusted_certs = True

Comment: Resolvi o problema momentaneamente fixando a versão do Firefox na 47.0.2

Answer (score 1):

Não entendo muito de `Selenium` em `C#`, pois sou mais adepto da versão para o `Python`, mas a ideia serve para os dois. Tente absorver a ideia e descobrir como reproduzir em `C#`.

Como adicionar o website às exceções de segurança não funcionou, você pode fazer o seu `WebDriver` clicar no link `"Avançar"` e depois em `"Continuar mesmo assim"`.

Mas... como fazer isso?

1. Você precisa descobrir qual o caminho do elemento na página para indicar ao `WebDriver` onde ele deve dar um `.click()`
2. Clique com o botão direito no link `"Avançar"` e selecione `"Inspecionar elemento"`
3. Descubra qual `identificador "único"` você pode utilizar para mostrar ao seu `WebDriver` onde encontrar o link "Avançar". Essa etapa é uma questão de estratégia e paciência!
4. Após encontrar um identificador único, como um `id`, `class`, `name` ou `text`, por exemplo, faça seu `WebDriver` encontrar este elemento e depois, clicar nele.

   - [Docs](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.jsp#locating-elements)
   - [Encontrar 1 elemento](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/P_OpenQA_Selenium_By_FindElementMethod.htm)
   - [Encontrar todos os elementos](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/P_OpenQA_Selenium_By_FindElementsMethod.htm)
5. Repita os passos de 2 a 4 para o link "Continuar mesmo assim."

---

**Códigos:**

- *Encontrar elem:* `links = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("a"));`
- *Clicar no elem:* `links.First(elem => elem.Text == "Avançar").Click();`

*ps: não testei pois não consegui reproduzir seu erro.*

---

**Como encontrar o identificador único:**

Exemplo utilizando o botão de descartar post no SOpt.

**1ª etapa:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

**2ª etapa:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

**3ª etapa:**

Posso utilizar como identificar único:

1. `class = btn-clear discard-answer`
2. `a`
3. `text = descartar`

Qual estratégia será a mais eficiente? Talvez a 1ª, mas pode-se utilizar qualquer uma das 3 estratégias para encontrar o botão.

Comment: Obrigado pelos detalhes.  
No Firefox é uma janela do próprio, como um alert.
Já vi algo sobre como selecionar um botão específico de um alert, mas não encontrei nada a respeito de outras janelas que não sejam o Alert. Ainda a procura. Obrigado!

Comment: @JamesTK veja [essa resposta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12745015/3846228) e a logo abaixo dela. O Selenium tem um 'alert handler', isto é, ele pode manipular alerts do navegador! No entanto, quando o alert é do sistema operacional, isto não é possível (como por exemplo as caixas que aparecem quando há o uso de certificado digital).